# How to hide firebaseConfig keys in Flutter Web

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, flutter, flutter-web

How can I hide keys and other private information in Flutter Web's `web/index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.3/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
      https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-web-app -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs//6.3.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.3/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.3/firebase-storage.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.3/firebase-functions.js"></script>

  <script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "API_KEY",
    authDomain: "authDomain.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "databaseURL.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "fir-projectId",
    storageBucket: "storageBucket.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "123456789",
    appId: "1:123456789:web:123456789"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```